# "Lit Quad Output" generates an error - Visual Effects Graph

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the Visual Effects Graph (unity 2018.3.0f2).

I'm trying to make smoke particles that reflect light (like in the demo:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUZzJcBIK80).

When I try choosing "Lit Quad Output"  it creates this error:

`Shader error in 'Hidden/VFX/System 2/Lit Quad Output': "Undefined punctual shadow filter algorithm" at /Users/user/Desktop/particle-test/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@4.1.0-preview/Runtime/Lighting/Shadow/HDShadowAlgorithms.hlsl(32) (on d3d11)`

`Compiling Vertex program with USE_CLUSTERED_LIGHTLIST SHADOW_LOW
Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR`

If I choose the "Quad Output" there are no errors, and it works fine. 
I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem which brought me to your question.

I fixed the issue by updating the High Definition RP package. This is done in the same way that Brackys adds/updates the Visual Effect Graph using the package manager.

Window > Package Manager > High Definition RP (4.9.0-preview in my case).

I had to restart the tutorial (delete the effect and re create it) to clear all errors and warnings.